# Could not find debuginfo for main pkg

Tags: debugging, centos, gdb, package

I'm trying to use gdb with my code, but it's giving me an error:

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install
blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
```

Trying to install the missing packages, but getting another error:

```
# debuginfo-install blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64

Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.gpmidi.net
 * extras: mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca
 * rpmforge: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.gpmidi.net
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-debuginfo-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-debuginfo-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

I downloaded a package, but when trying to install in manually, it says it's already installed:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 41a40948: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 is already installed
        file /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.2.1 from install of blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package blas-3.2.1-4.el6.x86_64
```

The OS is CentOS 6.7. Just in case, my /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo currently:

```
[base-debuginfo]
name=CentOS-6 - Debuginfo
baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6
enabled=1
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel your pain -- I'm having the same problem with CentOS 6.7.  Did you figure this out?  The error I got was asking me to install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64